# Why isn't lib in Python 3 install DOS PATH?

Tags: python-3.x, installation, path, pydoc

I installed Python 3.4 on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine. Works fine. I did choose the option to have Python added to the DOS PATH environment variable so that I could work at DOS command line, write python .py and it would work without having to type the full Python installation directory.

But when I tried to use pydoc, I discovered that it didn't know where pydoc was. Why? Because only Python34 and Python34\scripts are in the PATH. Why not also Python34/lib which has all sorts of useful tools, including pydoc.py?

Comment: I did successfully use pydoc by writing

python \Python34\Lib\pydoc.py <full_path_to_my_file_name>.py

Comment: But now that my Python program actually does something (contains executable code), the command above insists on first running my program, and only afterwards returns the formatted docstring information. How should I properly get the docstring info at the command line?

Answer (score 0):

If the command isn't bound, for whatever reason, Invoke pydoc with -m, e.g.

```
python -h
python -m pydoc some_file.py
```